# How to add "Sag" to cloth simulation?

Tags: modeling, physics, cloth-simulation

I am trying to create the net of a soccer goal using blender's cloth simulator. Right now the net looks really rigid and unrealistic. The cloth is a plane with subdivision and a wireframe modifier. I currently am pinning it on all 4 corners of the plane so that it stays attached to the goal. How do I make the cloth not seem so tight and rigid and add a bit of natural sag due to gravity?

[image: Soccer net showing how stiff it is]

[image]

Comment: I’ve tried to re-create this behaviour and I get the sag as expected - so I don’t know the issue in your case. Check your pinning to ensure that only the expected vertices are in the pinning vertex group. If that doesn’t help, can you upload your blend file so someone can examine it?

Comment: @RichSedman I have included the Blend file.

Comment: Your file is sagging nicely for me @Jacob Edie

Comment: As mentioned by @Coffeehouse, your file seems to 'sag' as would be expected. I have tested this by downloading your .blend and simply running the animation from the start, using Blender 2.76. Please re-try and let us know whether this is working. One issue could have been if you were still in Edit mode when you ran the animation or baked the simulation as this would have still kept the mesh in its initial state rather than showing the simulated result.

Comment: Thanks for the help I did not know how to clear the baked simulation. It now sags for me as well!